# How to handle OutOfMemoryException when a list gets too big?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox, out-of-memory

My application has two lists

```
public ObservableCollection<StreamItemViewModel> SearchStreamItems { get; private set; }
public ObservableCollection<StreamItemViewModel> MyStreamItems { get; private set; }
```

And each are the DataSource of one `ListBox`. Each time I click the button `more` the applications load 100 new items, and after a few clicks it throws a `OutOfMemoryException`.

Is there a way to avoid the exception? Or what should I do? Stop loading more updates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of loading *everything* which is neither possible nor really desirable  I would use a sliding window instead - when you reach a certain maximum list size (say i.e. 300 items) you automatically remove the top 100 items when you add the next 100 items to the bottom.

If you scroll just right after the update this shouldn't even be noticeable by your users.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want it to do when it can't load more.  You could  ignore it using a try catch like this:

```
try
{
    ... load more
}
catch (OutOfMemoryException)
{
    ... ignore or clear out old ones, then call call again
}
```

Or you could slim down the objects you're loading a bit so more can fit.  It just depends on what you think should be the allowed/accepted behavior.